# Why is onRestoreInstanceState inconsistent when screen dims

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I save state data in my activity's onSaveInstanceState function, and restore that data in onRestoreInstanceState. This code works fine 95% of the time.

I have found a test case that causes Android to produce different results from test to test, and I have no idea why. I have the original Droid phone, and it has a slide out keyboard. In my app, I perform 2 test cases that allow me to reproduce a situation where data is not restored because onRestoreInstanceState does not get called. The tests are nearly identical, but since I receive slightly different results, there obviously is something a bit different.

Test Case 1 (Phone in Portrait mode, keyboard in):

```
1. Populate the Activity with data
2. Press my phone's power button to purposely dim the screen. (The phone is now locked)
3. Immediately after step 2, slide out my phone's keyboard, switching the phone to landscape mode.
4. About 80% of the time, the screen lights up, giving me the option to unlock the phone. (See difference in other test case).
5. Unlock the phone, which immediately takes me to my last Activity. Function onRestoreInstanceState is not called about 75% of the time.
```

Test Case 2 (Phone in Landscape mode, keyboard is out):

```
1. Populate the Activity with data
2. Press my phone's power button to purposely dim the screen. (The phone is now locked)
3. Immediately after step 2, slide in my phone's keyboard, switching the phone to portrait mode.
4. Majority of the time, the screen is not lit up. I have to press my phone's power button to light the screen up, which then allows me to unlock the phone.
5. Unlock the phone, which immediately takes me to my last Activity. Function onRestoreInstanceState is not called about 20% of the time.
```

Test Case 1 does not restore the data about 60% of the time. Test Case 2 fails to restore the data about 20% of the time. The only difference that really stands out to me is the screen being lit after pushing in or sliding out the keyboard. When that screen lights up, the data is gone just about every time.

If I dim the screen, and then slide my keyboard in and out about 10 times in a row before unlocking the phone and going back to the app, I reproduce this problem *almost* 100% of the time.

In all cases where the data was restored successfully, here is the calling sequence:

```
onSave
onStop
onDestroy
onCreate
onStart
**onRestore**
onResume
```

In all cases where the data failed to be restored successfully, the calling sequence was:

```
onSave
onStop
onDestroy
onCreate
onStart
onResume
```

Can someone tell me what is going on here? Why do I get different results, performing the same exact test? If I run test case #1 (or #2) over and over, the results are never the same. I'd like to understand why this is happening, but more importantly (if a definitive answer is not possible), I just want the data to be saved each and every time, so what should I do? I thought moving the code that's in onRestoreInstanceState to onCreate would solve the problem, but I just ran my test cases a few times and saw that there are times where the Bundle passed to onCreate is null, which means my data doesn't get restored.

If I can't count on the Bundle in onCreate, and I can't count on onRestoreInstanceState being called, what's left? Is my only option onResume? This Activity maintains A LOT of data. Should I consider using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance and getLastNonConfigurationInstance, calling getLastNonConfigurationInstance in onResume? Previously I used these functions but I abandoned them due to suffering data loss. I didn't know why at the time, but I suspect it was because of this exact problem. But when I used them previously, I called getLastNonConfigurationInstance in onCreate. Perhaps it would be different/better if called from onResume?